# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Staticpages#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some problems with the partials. I'm trying to create flashes with bootstrap and I've put something I've found in Internet and that makes sense. But it doesn't work. The error says Showing C:/Users/David Soler/Desktop/diabetes_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #15 raised:

```
Missing partial shared/_flash_messages with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],     :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/David Soler/Desktop/diabetes_app/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
```

This is my code:

_flash_messages_html.erb

```
    <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(type) %> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

application.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DiabetesApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", :defer => "defer"  %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller], :defer => "defer" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script defer>

  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <%= render partial: "shared/flash_messages", flash: flash %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

application_helper.rb

```
    module ApplicationHelper

    def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    case flash_type
      when :success
        "alert-success"
      when :error
        "alert-error"
      when :alert
        "alert-block"
      when :notice
        "alert-info"
      else
        flash_type.to_s
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: is your partial named "_flash_messages.html.erb"?

Comment: The name of my partial is _flash_messages.html.erb

Comment: Your example shows `_flash_messages_html.erb` not `_flash_messages.html.erb`